# recognize visitors with javascript cookie for survey

Tags: javascript, cookies, unique, survey

I want people who visit my site for the first time to fill in a survey. I've got the code to show a popup which asks the user whether he wants to fill the survey, but I still don't have the code to recognize unique users. I searched more than 2 hours for it but I couldn't find it.

This are my requirements:

- I'm using wix.com, so I can't use php or asp, so I have to use javascript
- I'd like to use [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/), so visitors can't delete my cookie by accident

That latter isn't really necessary, but it would be handy because they can't be deleted.

Also I would like to relate to get the entire code and no examples. You can use **http://url.com** as the URL from the website where i stored my survey.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this really goes against the EU's policy about cookies: http://ec.europa.eu/ipg/standards/cookies/index_en.htm#section_2

However, I do recommend using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) with cookie fallback using [jstorage](http://www.jstorage.info/#reference),
you can get the code here: https://raw.github.com/andris9/jStorage/master/jstorage.min.js

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/eXZky/show/ | Source: http://fiddle.jshell.net/eXZky/

Using [evercookie](https://github.com/samyk/evercookie) will require additional browser plugins and even server side scripts.